# Construct a Xor Operation with || and &&, cannot run the right result

Tags: java, loops, logical-operators

The following code would ask users to input a line of binary number( like 01010011 ), then the program need to Xor the first digit with the second one, if the result is true, return 1, if not, return 0. Then Xor this result with the third digit... until the last digit. Following is my code, I tried it for the whole night, but never got the correct result. Can any one take a look at the code? Thank you!

```
    char input1;
    char input2;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.print("Please enter your value> ");
    input = scan.next();  


    input1 = input.charAt(0);

    for( int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++ )
    {
        input2 = input.charAt(i);

        if ( ( ( input1 == '1' || input2 == '0' ) && input1 != input2 )
                || ( ( input1 == '0' || input2 == '1' ) && input1 != input2 ) )
        {
            input1 = '1';
        }

        if ( input1 == input2 )
        {
            input1 = '0';
        }
    }

    System.out.println( "The result is " + input1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a `xor` method, return `'1'` **iff** `a` is one *or* `b` is one but both `a` and `b` are not one. Otherwise, return `'0'`. That is an exclusive-or. Like,

```
private static char xor(char a, char b) {
    boolean isa = (a == '1'), isb = (b == '1');
    if (isa || isb) {
        if (!(isa && isb)) {
            return '1';
        }
    }
    return '0';
}
```

Then your `main` needs to get the user input and iteratively `xor` the characters. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter your value> ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    char ch = input.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        ch = xor(ch, input.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println("The result is " + ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong in judgement, **when input1 is 0, input2 is 1, your code will be wrong**, it should be it:

```
    if ( ( ( input1 == '1' || input2 == '0' ) && input1 != input2 )
            || ( ( input1 == '0' || input2 == '1' ) && input1 != input2 ) )
    {
        input1 = '1';
    } 
    else if ( input1 == input2 )
    {
        input1 = '0';
    }
```